# 'BorderRadius?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BorderRadiusGeometry'

Tags: android, flutter

im trying to build apk and getting this error,
/C:/src/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/glass_kit-2.0.1/lib/src/glass_container.dart:406:41: Error: The argument type 'BorderRadius?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BorderRadiusGeometry' because 'BorderRadius?' is nullable and 'BorderRadiusGeometry' isn't.

- 'BorderRadius' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/border_radius.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/border_radius.dart').
- 'BorderRadiusGeometry' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/border_radius.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/border_radius.dart').
  current = ClipRRect(borderRadius: borderRadius, child: current);

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohqwh.png)

I tried to upgrage the flutter to stable. still same. help me to fix this

Comment: borderRadius value which you're proving to ClipRRect is nullable meaning it will have radius value or null but ClipRRect will only accept non-null value here.
 current = ClipRRect(borderRadius: borderRadius, child: current);  so you need to define a default value for borderRadius.

Comment: what does your code look like

Comment: Actually I'm a beginner, i din't know. Where is the error coming from.

Comment: Using this https://github.com/bharat-1809/glass_kit

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.